Pop!_OS 22.04 LTS - How to avoid Grub recovery upon restart
I am new to Linux. After playing with installation of NVIDIA drivers and CUDA utils on my Dell laptop which has Pop!_OS 22.04 LTS and Windows installed, and doing some updates which I don't really remember, upon restart I get into a "grub>" kind of environment, whereas before I had a blue screen which chooses the operation system. I found online that the following set of commands puts me back into the blue screen:
set prefix=(hd0,gpt7)/boot/grub
set root=(hd0,gpt7)
insmod linux
insmod normal
normal

and everything seems normal then. I also read that I should run
sudo update-grub

in the linux terminal and the "grub>" think should not reappear, but I ran it and the "grub>" thing still appears upon restart. Does anyone know how to get rid of it for a novice?
Thanks!

The sudo update-grub just updates the menu. It sounds like grub is not correctly installed. Did you do UEFI install as almost all systems now are UEFI, or an old BIOS type install? I so not use Pop!_OS, but its default install does not use grub, but uses SystemD boot. Not sure how to fix SystemD boot, but if you did install using grub and it is UEFI, you just need to run sudo grub-install once booted. It will reinstall using ESP - efi system partition in /etc/fstab. May want to check first that the ESP entry is correct. cat /etc/fstab & lsblk -f

Unfortunately I don't know enough to be able to check the things you ask about. I believe I installed using grub though. Is it safe to run sudo grub-install or it can cause some further damage?

Then we need details. Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the BootInfo summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed. Use often updated ppa version with your USB installer or any working install over somewhat older ISO.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair &
https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/ Do not think Boot-Repair can fix SystemD boot, but report will show your configuration. Boot-Repair's most common fix is grub update or grub reinstall.

@oldfred Thanks! Here it is: http://sprunge.us/qYDhMC

You show two ESP on same drive p1 & p8. Many systems only work with one per drive. Back up ESP on p8, change partuuid entry in /etc/fstab to partuuid of p1 and reinstall grub. To see partuuids you can use sudo blkid and then edit sudoedit /etc/fstab with p1 partUUID. The run the complete reinstall of grub sudo grub-install.  Be sure to have good backups as any change can go create issues. And always have live installer or Windows repair/recovery drive for current installed version.

@oldfred Thank you, that sounds a bit complicated for me, I will try to understand details somewhat later. Isn't there a simple way, similar in spirit to a shell script, where the system "types" for me the commands I wrote in my question instead of me doing it each time? It seems to work just fine when I type these and boot.

I have occasionally used configfile. That is the grub command used to change from /EFI/ubuntu/grub.cfg  (on my system) to /boot/grub/grub.cfg.  Yours may be configfile (hd0,7)/boot/grub/grub.cfg
